# Robospice RequestListener does not work with offline task

Tags: android, listener, offline, robospice

i've got really weird problem. I'm trying to use Robospice for not-networking task (JSON serialization/deserialization).

I've implemented SpiceService (based on offline example from Robospice github) and Requests - doing serialization stuff in loadDataFromNetwork().

I start and stop SpiceManager in OnStart() and OnStop().

My problem is that request is executing but **listener is not fired** (None of OnRequestSuccess and OnRequestFailure methods are fired)

Here is the line of code responsible for executing task

```
 manager.execute(saveRequest, new SaveRequestListener());
```

and my listener

```
private class SaveRequestListener implements com.octo.android.robospice.request.listener.RequestListener<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException spiceException) {
        Log.d("saving",spiceException.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Some error :(((", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(Boolean aBoolean) {
        Log.d("saving","Saved!!! " + aBoolean);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Saved!!! " + aBoolean, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any chance that you are stopping the `SpiceManager` before expecting the callback?

In that case, the request will finish as it has already been started, but the `RequestListener` will never be called since the request listeners are automatically detached. It works this way in order to make sure contexts will not be leaking.

Comment: it was that :) i was executing request in onClickListener, and after click I was also making transistion to other fragment, so onStop method was called when I was stopping Manager, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try ctrl+i or ctrl+o in android studio to reimplamentate the methods. And check the input and output types of methods.